# Proving interior of a set is empty

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis

Given that $F$ is a closed set and $A$ an arbitrary subset in a metric space that $A^\circ = F^\circ = \varnothing$. Prove that $(F \cup A)^\circ = 
\varnothing$

I'm trying to solve this and I've just started with Analysis. I would appreciate it if anyone could give me a hint.

Comment: This seems to be the Baire category Theorem  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baire_category_theorem

Comment: I wasn't able to understand that. can you help me with a hint?

Comment: In this case we cannot use it, because in the hypothesis of your problem the space is not complete

Comment: You probably want to solve the dual problem with closures. That is, if $F$ is open and both $F$ and $A$ are dense, then $F \cap A$ is also dense.

Comment: I think I could solve the dual problem if the metric space were complete, here in this case the assumption is weaker.

Answer (score 1):

Under the given assumption of closed $F$ and $A$ any, holds $(F \cup A)^\circ \subset F \cup (A)^{\circ}$. In fact, let $x \in (F \cup A)^\circ$, so there is some open set $W$ containing $x$ and $W \subset (F \cup A)^\circ$. If $x\in F$ we are done. Suppose that $x \notin F$. Then $F$ closed, implies that its complement in the given metric space is open. Taking the intersection of $W$ with the complement of $F$, we have an open containing $x$, contained in $A$ (is contained in $(F \cup A)\cap(F^{c}) \subset A$), and which does not intersect $F$, so $x$ is in $A^{\circ}$. In this way the inclusion is proved.

Maybe you could use a contradiction argument, if the interior of the union $F \cup A$ is non-empty, then how $A^{\circ} = \emptyset$, the inclusion above becomes $(F \cup A)^\circ \subset F$. Contradiction about the fact that the interior of $F$ is empty.

Comment: I actually thought a lot about that but what if the open set contains elements from both F and A which isn't in A $\cap$ F?

Comment: correct me, in case I'm thinking wrong. But I believe that this situation cannot happen, because if the open contained a point of $F$, as $F$ is closed, that point would be the limit point of a sequence of $F$, then you could build a neighborhood of this limit point totally contained in $F$, the which gives a contradiction again, since the interior of $F$ is empty.

Comment: I found a better proof and added it above, I think it's clearer now!

Comment: I can't see why the last line is a contradiction. also in the third line "if $x \in F$ we are done". can you elaborate?

Comment: the contradiction in the last line is because you have a non-empty open inside $F$. In the third line it's because if $x$ is in $F$ then the inclusion is already valid, so I analyze the case of $x$ outside of $F$.

Answer (score 1):

Proof by Contradiction :
Suppose $\mathcal x \in (A \cup F)^\circ$. Then there exists r such that $N_r(\mathcal x) \subseteq (A \cup F)$.
We know that there exists $\mathcal a \in N_r(\mathcal x), a \notin F$.Otherwise $N_r(\mathcal x) \subseteq F$, Which is in Contradiction with $F^\circ = \varnothing$.
Since F is closed $\exists \ell$ $N_\ell(\mathcal x) \, \cap F = \varnothing$. And we know that any  open ball is an open set. hence $N_r(\mathcal x)$ is open, meaning $\exists \alpha$ $\ N_\alpha(\mathcal x) \ \subseteq N_r(\mathcal x).$
Now by only choosing $\beta < \alpha ,\ell$ we can conclude that  $N_\beta(\mathcal x) \ \subseteq A$. And that is in Contradiction with $F^\circ = \varnothing$.Therefore $(A \cup F)^\circ = \varnothing.$